# How to alias a left joined table in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Basically I have a situation where I made two left outer joins in my laravel query and now I want to select two columns and put one alias for them, if one column is null use the other columns value for that new aliased column. Something like NVL in SQL. Any suggestions?

I tried something like ...->select('one or other as newName'); but it won't work.

Edit: I have a table for articles that I join with user, news_groups and magazine_groups. Article that has news_group won't have magazine_group. I want to show those together in one joined column in select using alias.

```
DB::table('articles')
        ->leftJoin('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'articles.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('news_groups', 'news_groups.id', '=', 'articles.news_group_id')
        ->leftJoin('magazine_groups', 'magazine_groups.id', '=', 'articles.magazine_groups_id')
        ->select('articles.id', 'type', 'title', 'articles.published_at',
            'users.first_name','users.last_name', 'news_groups.name or magazine_groups.name as group_name')
        ->groupBy('articles.id');
```

Comment: A complete code example would be appreciated. Could you do a raw sql instead of using the ORM?

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Like most questions on SO if you show your code you will get a much better and quicker response from the community.

Comment: Sorry, here it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to use a [Raw Expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions):

```
DB::table('articles')
        ->leftJoin('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'articles.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('news_groups', 'news_groups.id', '=', 'articles.news_group_id')
        ->leftJoin('magazine_groups', 'magazine_groups.id', '=', 'articles.magazine_groups_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('articles.id, type, title, articles.published_at, users.first_name, users.last_name, COALESCE(news_groups.name, magazine_groups.name) as group_name'))
        ->groupBy('articles.id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions  Raw expressions.

You might try something like this :

```
->select(DB::RAW('IFNULL(news_groups.name,magazine_groups.name) AS groupname,articles.id..other selects'))
```